# CSS Grid. My current layout working as expected on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

```css
:root {
    --text-color:#fff;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 10px;
    background: #ddd;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: goldenrod;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.rightcontainer {
    background: blue;
    padding: 25px;
}

.rightcontainer .links {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.leftcontainer {
    background: green;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.leftcontainer__feature-articles {
    background: yellow;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.leftcontainer__feature-article1 {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}   

.leftcontainer__feature-article2 {
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
} 

.leftcontainer__recent-articles {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.leftcontainer__recent-articles > div{
    padding: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
}

.leftcontainer__recent-articles > div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.recent-contentholder {
    padding: 10px;
    
}
.recent-time-added {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.leftcontainer__feature-articles > div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.leftcontainer__feature-article1 img, 
.leftcontainer__feature-article2 img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

.leftcontainer__feature-article1 div,
.leftcontainer__feature-article2 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>NewBlog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif:400,700|Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="leftcontainer">
            <div class="leftcontainer__feature-articles">
                <div class="leftcontainer__feature-article1">
                    <img src="//source.unsplash.com/random/500x500?v=1" alt="">
                    <div class="feature-contentholder">
                        <h2 class="feature-title">Title1</h2>
                        <small class="feature-time-added">
                            Tuesday 30 23:58
                        </small>
                        <p class="feature-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur modi cumque et labore sunt
                            non!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftcontainer__feature-article2">
                    <img src="//source.unsplash.com/random/500x500?v=1" alt="">
                    <div class="feature-contentholder">
                        <h2 class="feature-title">Title1</h2>
                        <small class="feature-time-added">
                            Tuesday 30 23:58
                        </small>
                        <p class="feature-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur modi cumque et labore sunt
                            non!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="leftcontainer__recent-articles">
                <div class="leftcontainer__recent-article1">
                    <img src="//source.unsplash.com/random/300x300?v=1" alt="">
                    <div class="recent-contentholder">
                        <h2 class="recent-title">Title1</h2>
                        <small class="recent-time-added">
                            Tuesday 30 23:58
                        </small>
                        <p class="recent-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur modi cumque et labore sunt
                            non!
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftcontainer__recent-article2">
                    <img src="//source.unsplash.com/random/300x300?v=2" alt="">
                    <div class="recent-contentholder">
                        <h2 class="recent-title">Title2</h2>
                        <small class="recent-time-added">
                            Tuesday 30 23:58
                        </small>
                        <p class="recent-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur modi cumque et labore sunt
                            non!
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftcontainer__recent-article3">
                    <img src="//source.unsplash.com/random/300x300?v=3" alt="">
                    <div class="recent-contentholder">
                        <h2 class="recent-title">Title3</h2>
                        <small class="recent-time-added">
                            Tuesday 30 23:58
                        </small>
                        <p class="recent-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur modi cumque et labore sunt
                            non!
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftcontainer__recent-article4">
                    <img src="//source.unsplash.com/random/300x300?v=4" alt="">
                    <div class="recent-contentholder">
                        <h2 class="recent-title">Title4</h2>
                        <small class="recent-time-added">
                            Tuesday 30 23:58
                        </small>
                        <p class="recent-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur modi cumque et labore sunt
                            non!
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightcontainer">
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">first post</a>
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">second post</a>
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">third post</a>
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">fourth post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

`img` tags inside `leftcontainer__feature-article1` and `leftcontainer__feature-article2` on chrome sit inside parent taking full width and height as expected, but on firefox im facing issue.

I tried adding `max-width` and `max-height` to parent and img then it'll work on firefox and itll fail to work on chrome.

I'm trying to do this since forever I'm unable to figure out what's wrong. I want to know where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by adding `max-width` and `max-height` of the container holding img tag to 100% and `min-width` and `min-height` to 0 and `max-height` and `width` of img to 100% and 100% resp.